# Getting data from one database and process and store it to another database using trident topology

Tags: apache-storm, trident

I want to get data from one database through a spout and process the data and store it in another database using trident.I am new to storm and trident and i am not sure how to implement it.I got the data from the database in a spout(separate java class which implements IRichSpout which is supported by trident) and i emit it as an object.I need to pass it to the trident topology for processing(counting the number of records) and storing it to a database.

```
 TridentTopology topology = new TridentTopology();  
 TridentState wordCounts =
          topology.newStream("spout1",spout)
```

now the new stream takes a spout as an input i.e the syntax is

```
 Stream storm.trident.TridentTopology.newStream(String txId, IRichSpout spout)
```

but i want to give the object emitted by the spout as an input to the stream for the trident to process and save to database.So how can i bring my spout class inside trident and pass it to new stream or should i combine both spout and trident as a same class??

can someone help plz.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
    MyFooSpout spout = new MyFooSpout();
    topology.newStream("spout1", spout)....
```

Where the `MyFooSpout` class should implements the `IRichSpout`

From the [trident tutorial](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Trident-tutorial)
The `newStream` method in `TridentTopology` creates a stream of data in the topology reading from any input source.

In your case it could be the `MyFooSpout` class

> .I got the data from the database in a spout(separate java class which implements IRichSpout which is supported by trident) and i emit it as an **object**

can you please clarify what exactly are you referring to? How is your spout code looks like? As a   very generic example if we write something like (taken from the tutorial page)

```
    TridentState wordCounts = topology.newStream("spout1", spout).each(new Fields("sentence"), new Split(), new Fields("word"))
```

it means that the `spout` supposed to emit a single field namely `sentence`. By calling `each` the `Split` function will be applied to each tuple in the stream, which will perform based on whatever code is written by taking the `sentence` field. However this could vary depending on your requirement. e.g it could be a `Filter` as `MyFilter extends BaseFilter` Or a `function` as `MyCustomFuction extends BaseFunction`. Check out the API page for more details.